# Sidecar not working between MBP 15' 2019 and iPad Pro 9.7'

Tags: ipad, airplay, sidecar

I just updated both my ipad to IpadOS and my MBP to Catalina and I'm trying to setup sidecar.

I made sure that:

- both are on the same wifi network
- I'm logged in with the same iCloud account on both
- Bluetooth is on

I don't have the AirPlay icon in the menu bar nor can I see the iPad in System Preferences > Sidecar.

What else can I try to make it work?

Comment: I just fixed mine: restart both MBP and iPad > sign out on both from iCloud accounts > sign in again to iCloud > restart both. Then open system preferences > open sidecar from there and select iPad. That just fixed it for me, try it out. Btw make sure both have two way authentication factor enabled.

Comment: @shadesco Almost there, now I can see the icon and my ipac but when I try to connect I get "Unable to connect, wifi is not enabled on the device".

Comment: @shadesco One more restart solved the issue, thanks :)

Comment: Perfect glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked to solve the issue:

```
- Logout from iCloud on both devices
- Restart both devices
- Login to iCloud on both deviced
- Restart both devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to plug the iPad on the MBP ?
It should work with Bluetooth connection, but just to try...
Wifi network does not have an influence on Sidecar.